# HTML/JS: Empty formdata in click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML/JS, where I try to extract the formdata:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" 
                type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform input[type=submit]").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fd = new FormData($("#myform")[0]);
        console.log(fd);
        fds = JSON.stringify(fd);
        console.log(fds);
    });
 });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myform" method="POST" enc-type="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="test" type="hidden" value="5" />
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="X" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Executing the page delivers empty FormData. Why? Is there an alternative for JSON.stringify?

Comment: Try this fds = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray()); @Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Use `.serializeArray()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform input[type=submit]").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $('#myform').serializeArray();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks - that works. Can I reconstruct the FormData object from JSON.stringify(formData) for a postponed submit of the form? (I want to store JSON.stringify(formData) into localStorage).

Comment: Try this for localstorage localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData)) @Stefan

Comment: Ok, but how do I inserve the function to be able to set the data attribute in an AJAX call?

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(localStorage['formData']). This will return your formData back .can you update your question briefly so it could be easy to understand and answer @Stefan

Comment: @Preethi Mano: so far so good, data needs nows to be put into FormData, in order to be submitted with a jQuery.ajax()-call. In addition, I have to cope with input type="file", too.

Comment: Very sorry. I can't get your point.Plz update your question so that it can be easy for you to get the exact solution for your answer.@Stefan

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform input[type=submit]").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fd = $("#myform").serialize();
      
        alert(fd)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" method="POST" enc-type="multipart/form-data">
            
  <input name="test" type="hidden" value="5" />
           
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="X" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach, but it the solutions omits the submit value for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud read fields from FormData before serialize :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform input[type=submit]").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fd = new FormData($("#myform")[0]);
        console.log(fd);
        fds = JSON.stringify(fd.getAll());
        console.log(fds);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use serialize(),like this:

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){
         var fm_data=fm.serialize();
         console.log(fm_data);
    })
```

look this:https://api.jquery.com/serialize/